# CUDA replicating an array in constant memory

Tags: memory, cuda, constants

I have a mapping table which I know I can copy to CUDA constant memory by doing the following:

```
#define LENGTH 4
#define THREAD_BLOCKS 64

const int mapTable[LENGTH] = {0, 1, 3, 5};

int main()
{
  //..

__constant__ int dMapTable[LENGTH];
cudaMemcpyToSymbol( dMapTable , mapTable, size_t(LENGTH) * sizeof(int) , 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  //..
}
```

Now what I want to do is to create multiple copies of this table in CUDA constant memory. The number of copies I want to create is equal to number of thread Blocks THREAD_BLOCKS. Can anyone advise me how to do this and to do this efficiently ?

Comment: What's the motivation for this ? Do you think it will improve performance ? (I doubt it.)

Comment: Actually all threads of my kernel are reading this array in constant memory. I am not using any shared memory so far and the statistics from computeprof tell me that around 3 million warp executions serialize. Also, from my algorithm I know that different threads will be reading different and unpredictable locations in this array. By replicating this array I can amortize the cost incurred due to warp serializing from the bank conflicts

Comment: Why not just copy the constants to shared memory ?

Comment: Yes I did think about that but I am thinking of utilizing shared memory for other memory optimizations. Actually I am still not sure if replicating the array in constant memory can reduce the warp divergence because threads in half warp will still access locations according to the same pattern

Comment: Constant memory is not for reading different and unpredictable locations. You should try texture memory for this scenario or the global memory in devices of compute capability > 2.x as the cache hierarchy will do the job of cache data quite well.

Comment: For this application, if you can't use shared, the L1 cache might work well.  Constant memory is optimized for broadcast, so definitely not what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if you see any improvement in kernel performance by setting up multiple copies of your constant data. The constant memory is cached, so you would just be thrashing the cache with duplicated values.

Also, it's worth noting that the constant memory size is only 64KiB on all devices up to compute capability 3.0.

Still, if you want to check performance, just set up the multiple copies like you normally would and then time the kernel.

Comment: Yep. And the constant cache is *small*.